Curviliner integral $z^p$
Regarding the famous derivation of the Equation of Time available here that i'm trying to rewrite a modern version with much more detailed steps:
http://info.ifpan.edu.pl/firststep/aw-works/fsII/mul/mueller.pdf
There is a curvilinear integral at page 5, relation (14):
$$\oint z^p \mathrm{~d} z=\int_{\mathrm{e}^0}^{\mathrm{e}^{4 \mathrm{i} \pi}} z^p \mathrm{~d} z=\left\{\begin{array}{cll}0 & \text { for } & p \neq-1 \\ 4 \mathrm{i} \pi & \text { for } & p=-1\end{array}\right.$$
I don't understand where this solution comes from.
This is how i did so far:
$$\oint z^p \mathrm{~d} z=\int_{e^0}^{e^{4 \mathrm{i} \pi}} z^p \mathrm{~d} z=\left.\frac{z^{(p+1)}}{p+1}\right|_{e^0} ^{e^{4 \mathrm{i} \pi}}=\dfrac{1}{p+1}-\dfrac{1}{p+1}=0$$
Thanks for your help...

this works for $p\neq-1$

@SineoftheTime Hmmm.... i must be tired. I will take some rest and look at it again. It must be too obvious.

not happy with the notation here. From reading the PDF I think the integral is supposed to traverse the unit circle twice, which means that the winding number around $0$ of the curve we're integrating over is $2$, and you get $4 \pi i$ in the $p = -1$ case and $0$ otherwise from e.g. the Residue theorem. If someone just wrote $\int_z^w$ for complex numbers $z, w$, I would ordinarily assume that the integral is taken over the line segment connecting (starting at) $z$ and (ending at) $w$.

@SineoftheTime Ok indeed i just needed some rest. The answer was obvious. I need to sleep more. Thanks for your help anyway.

@GeorgeCoote Yes i also noticed that. Very likely that's because the author of the document is a physicist....
